# Where can I find photos taken by a particular lens?

Tags: lens

Before buying a lens I would like to see what kind of pictures it can take. Which websites let me see all the photos previously taken online by a particular lens (or a lens/camera combo)?

Comment: on a small scale: most review sites have a section with their test shots.

Comment: flickr, 500px (and probably a lot of other sites)

Comment: Try www.shutterdial.com by Flickr

Comment: This is a generally on-topic and interesting question, but these kind of things tend to be terrible for Stack Exchange, because they result in a random unmaintained list of links.

Comment: You want to see **all** the photos taken with a given lens?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [PixelPeeper](https://pixelpeeper.com/) for that. It is a site which was made specially for this purpose.

Comment: As of 22 December 2022, I can't find a way to use PixelPeeper to browse any kind of gallery of images to find photos from a given lens.

Comment: @phantomraa indeed, the site is completely different now than it was 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the well-established image sharing sites, such as [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) and [500px](https://500px.com/), are searchable by lens model.

For example, if you want to see images taken with the Canon EF 135mm f/2 L lens, just go to [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/), type in "EF 135mm f/2 L" in the search box in the upper right hand corner of their main page, select "Photos" from the dropdown menu, and you'll get a plethora of images with that lens in the EXIF info.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Most other image sharing sites can be similarly searched by lens.

Answer (score 1):

Another place is dpreview.com https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries?category=lenses